# Excel/VBA is eating more than 1 apostrophe when appending them to the front of a string

Tags: vba, excel

I have some disjoint data in a list that I'm  fixing by concatenating the data back together. Unfortunately some of the break points have apostrophe's right on the breakpoint causing excel to omit said apostrophe (which causes delimiting issues later).

The data is fragmented as follows:

```
(18547,'royalcaribbean','VY04I239','4 Night  Sanya & Chan May Cruise','Voyager of the Seas',4,'Hong Kong','2016-07-17 00:00:00',862,942,1022,1102,0,0,0,0,'2016-05-21 08:11:14'),(18714,'royalcaribbean','VY04I240','4 Night  Sanya & Chan May Cruise','Voyager of the Seas',4,'Hong Kong','2016-08-05 00:00:00',902,969,1119,1129,0,0,0,0,'2016-05-21 08:11:25'),(18277,'royalcaribbean','VY04I241','4 Night  Sanya & Chan May Cruise','Voyager of the Seas',4,'Hong Kong','2016-09-15 00:00:00',729,796,876,982,0,0,0,0,'2016-05-21 08:10:56'),(18122,'royalcaribbean','VY04I242','4 Night  Kaohsiung & Taipei Cruise','Voyager of the Seas',4,'Hong Kong','2016-10-07 00:00:00',662,729,796,916,0,0,0,0,'2016-05-21 08:10:43'),(18266,'royalcaribbean','VY04I251','4 Night  Kaohsiung & Taipei Cruise','Voyager of the Seas',4,'Hong Kong','2016-08-27 00:00:00',737,814,886,982,0,0,0,0,'2016-05-21 08:10:55'),(18465,'royalcaribbean','VY05I279','5 Night  Nha Trang & Chan May Cruise','Voyager of the Seas',5,'Hong Kong','2016-06-21 00:00:00',796,889,982,0,0,0,0,0,'2016-05-21 08:11:08'),(18466,'royalcaribbean','VY05I279','5 Night  Nha Trang & Chan May Cruise','Voyager of the Seas',5,'Hong Kong','2016-07-26 00:00:00
',1116,1209,1289,1472,0,0,0,0,'2016-05-21 08:11:08'),(18793,'royalcaribbean','VY05I280','5 Night  Best Of Okinawa Cruise','Voyager of the Seas',5,'Hong Kong','2016-06-26 00:00:00',995,1036,1102,1222,0,0,0,0,'2016-05-21 08:11:32'),(18794,'royalcaribbean','VY05I280','5 Night  Best Of Okinawa Cruise','Voyager of the Seas',5,'Hong Kong','2016-07-03 00:00:00',942,1036,1129,1249,0,0,0,0,'2016-05-21 08:11:32')
```

In row 2 excel does not show that leading apostrophe. When I loop through my data I've tried adding chr(39) to the start but excel removes that one too! I've added two of them but that adds an apostrophe to data that did not have an apostrophe before. Why is excel eating a second apostrophe?

```
'Replaces the delimiter between rows by a strange character ~
ch1 = Chr(19)
Selection.Replace What:="),(", Replacement:=ch1, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
'Starts the separation process
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A" & dataRowstart), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
:=ch1, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
'Heals data that was chopped in the inital copy into the spreadsheet
For i = dataRowstart + 1 To dataRowEnd 'For each row append the data
    SQLData.Cells(i, 1).Value = Chr(39) & SQLData.Cells(i, 1).Value 'add apostrophe
    SQLData.Cells(i - 1, FindNextEmpty(SQLData.Cells(i - 1, 1)).Column - 1).Value = SQLData.Cells(i - 1, FindNextEmpty(SQLData.Cells(i - 1, 1)).Column - 1).Value & Right(SQLData.Cells(i, 1).Value, Len(SQLData.Cells(i, 1).Value) - 1)
    SQLData.Cells(i, 1).Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft 'After concatenating delete the broken piece
Next i
```

Comment: I assume this is caused by excel treating a single apostrophe leading a field as designating the field is a character field?

Comment: Show us more of the code - I'll guarantee that this is something you should be using `Split()` and arrays for.

Comment: @Joe Yes, the issue is that the leading apostrophe in excel indicates that this is text. Most solutions online say that if you want a leading apostrophe then append two of them. But if you already have a leading one then appending another one doesn't make your string start with char(39)

Comment: @MacroMan I added more code and showed more raw data. Rows for the data will start where ),( is and then the items are delimited by comma. Unfortunately the fragmentation is what's causing the issue. I'll look into using Split()

Comment: @cg Where is the data coming from?  Maybe we should start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regular Expressions, and your sample, it seems easy to create a rule that would replace the missing single quote.

Being uncertain of all of your CleanUp requirements, I'm not sure how this would fit in.  But after concatenating the lines, the regex pattern looks for a string that

- Starts with `comma` followed by `single-quote`
- Series of characters that are **NOT** a `single-quote`
- Followed by a `comma`

Then do a replace such that we add a `single-quote` prior to the comma.

```
Option Explicit
Function ReplaceMissingQuote(R As Range) As String
    Dim S As String
    Dim C As Range
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "(,'[^']+?),"
    Const sRepl As String = "$1',"

'Initialize Regex Engine
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = sPat
End With

'Concatenate the lines
For Each C In R
    S = S & C.Text
Next C

'Replace the missing single quote
S = RE.Replace(S, sRepl)

ReplaceMissingQuote = S

End Function
```

Here is an explanation of the Regex patterns used:

### (,'[^']+?),

sPat:    (,'[^']+?),

Options: Case sensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 `(,'[^']+?)`

  - Match the character string “,'” literally `,'`
  - Match any character that is NOT a “'” `[^']+?`

    - Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) `+?`
- Match the character “,” literally `,`

sRepl:  $1',

- Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 `$1`
- Insert the character string “',” literally `',`

Created with RegexBuddy

**EDIT**:  Looking at your code, I wonder if the following would be helpful.  As before, we

- concatenate everything (in column 1 in this case) into a long string
- replace the missing single quotes
- replace the `),(`sequence with `)cr-lf(`
- write it back to the worksheet in separate lines.

You'll probably need to change the location of the source data, as well as where you want to write the results, but it should get you started

```
Sub CleanUp()
    Dim V As Variant, S As String
    Dim vTemp As Variant
    Dim R As Range
    Dim RE As Object
    Const sPat As String = "(,'[^']+?),"
    Const sRepl As String = "$1',"
    Const sPat2 As String = "\),\("
    Const sRepl2 As String = ")" & vbCrLf & "("
    Dim I As Long

'Initialize Regex engine
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    RE.Global = True

'Concatenate the lines
V = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
For Each vTemp In V
    S = S & vTemp
Next vTemp

'Put back the single quote
With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    S = .Replace(S, sRepl)

'Split at "),("
    .Pattern = sPat2
    S = .Replace(S, sRepl2)
End With

'Place each line into separate cells
vTemp = Split(S, vbCrLf)

ReDim V(1 To UBound(vTemp), 1 To 1)
For I = 1 To UBound(V)
    V(I, 1) = vTemp(I)
Next I

Set R = Range("C3").Resize(UBound(V, 1))
R = V
R.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Given the data you presented, the output looks like:

[image]